# Can a child template extend from variable contents instead of a file on disk?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm writing a child template which currently extends from a base file. I would like to store the base file and subsequent changes/extensions into a variable, but I'm not sure how to have a child template extend from variable contents instead of a file name.

I'm using Ansible and Jinja to create a sort of "string builder" for a config file. I'm currently using:

attr1.jinja:

`{% extends 'base_file.jinja' %}`

But I would like my playbook to use set_fact and extend successively like so:

```
hosts: localhost
vars: 
  - var_builder: "{{ lookup('file', 'base_file.jinja') }}"

tasks:
  - name: Extend from base_file
    set_fact:
      var_builder: "{{ lookup('template', 'attr1.jinja') }}"

  - name: Extend from var_builder
    set_fact:
      var_builder: "{{ lookup('template', 'attr2.jinja') }}"
```

I think this would require the attr.jinja files to somehow extend from the contents of a variable but `{% extends _ %}` seems to only accept string file names. I could just keep successively overwriting a temp file, but I was hoping there was another way to do this.